# how can we pass the variable into the function via url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have designed an ASP.NET page which create graphs.

I have written a class file (which contain a function to render the graph, a function for entering data named `insertdata(string[] s,double[] d)`) in App_code folder.

I pass the value into the insertdata during `page_load` event.

I saw a feature of **googlechart** where you pass the value via URL it will create
a graph according to that passed value.

How can i pass the value into the `insertdata()` function through the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Request.QueryString. e.g.

```
http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?mayvar=someval
```

With the above URL

```
Request.QueryString["myvar"]
```

in the codebehind for somepage.aspx the above will return "someval" ;

Comment: explain it with some more example i cant get your view

Comment: Google is your friend.  You can't explain it much simpler than that

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more info on QueryStrings,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Request/SendandgetquerystringC.htm

Google it and you'll find lots of information.